# Chrome and IE display diffrence

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a table

```
<tr>Page header goes here</>
<tr valign="top">
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top">
            <center>
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr height="29%">
                            <td height="29%">
                                 // to display the below tr in center of page
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="31%">
                            <td bgcolor="FFFFFF" height="31%" align="center" valign="top">
                                <table width="40%" height="31%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="16">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/top_lef.gif")" width="16" height="100%" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td height="16" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/top_mid.gif")')">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/top_mid.gif")" width="16" height="100%" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="24">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/top_rig.gif")" width="24" height="100%" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="16" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/cen_lef.gif")')">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/cen_lef.gif")" width="16" height="100%" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td bgcolor="#F7F8FB" valign="top">
                                                <div style="height: 30px;">
                                                </div>
                                                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                                {
                        //login details username and password
                                                }
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="24" style="background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/cen_rig.gif")')">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/cen_rig.gif")" width="24" height="100%" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="16" height="16">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/bot_lef.gif")" width="16" height="16" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td height="16" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/bot_mid.gif")')">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/bot_mid.gif")" width="16" height="16" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="24" height="16">
                                                <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/images/bot_rig.gif")" width="24" height="16" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="39%">
                            <td height="39%">
                                 // to display the above tr in center of page
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>Page footer goes here</>
```

I have added a tr and td with with 20 and 31% above and below the main body where my login controls go

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

but in IE the login control is displayed in center but in chrome the login is displayed right after page header. Its seems as if the height of 29% is not considered. I tried adding 
 but the result is not the same in both browsers.

I was looking for a neater way to solve this. If any one can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use tables for a new site layout. There are a lot better methodes out there. Take a look at div's, please.

Comment: What is the issue with using tables.

Comment: Read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html